# Spring Boot can't deserialize json array

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

So I have this form

- [register.html](https://github.com/Dummyapt/Internship/blob/testing/src/main/resources/templates/register.html)

and I'm trying to use the values of the input fields in my RequestBody so that my app can create an user

- [RegistrationControllerREST.java](https://github.com/Dummyapt/Internship/blob/testing/src/main/java/de/dummyapt/internship/registration/RegistrationControllerREST.java)
- [RegistrationService.java](https://github.com/Dummyapt/Internship/blob/testing/src/main/java/de/dummyapt/internship/registration/RegistrationService.java)

but everytime it prints out the following error

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `de.dummyapt.internship.registration.RegistrationRequest` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `de.dummyapt.internship.registration.RegistrationRequest` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`) at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]]
```

Comment: edit your question to include code instead of screenshots

Comment: Please showcase at what point is your error happening? Like code :)

Such an exception occurs when you are passing an empty array, that does not have RegistrationRequest.

Also..your input requestbody is of type (@RequestBody RegistrationRequest request), not an Array of them....

Comment: You got formdate in Ajax call alert message?

Comment: Add your dependency pom file or gradle file. Did you have all jackson dependency?

Answer (score 0):

As your error message already describes, Spring tries to parse an object of type "RegistrationRequest" from a JSON array.

To make this work, you have to pass a JSON object to the controller, not an array. At the moment you're serializing your data as an array (`serializeArray()`)

Answer (score 0):

You should either pass formData as a JSON object or if you want to pass formData as a list you should change your controller to accept list from UI.

Answer (score 0):

From your register.html you sent user data via HTML form / submit. In this case u need to use @ModelAttribute annotation on controller method.

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public String register(@ModelAttribute RegistrationRequest request) {
    return registrationService.register(request);
}
```

@ModelAttribute annotation mapping automatically between HTML name attribute and variables.
So u should add name attribute on your form and match these with name of variables in RegistrationRequest class

```
<form id="registerForm" th:action="@{/register}" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="fadeIn second" id="username" name="username" required>
                    <label for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="fadeIn second" id="email" name="email" required>
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="fadeIn third" id="password" name="password" required>
                    <label for="passwordConfirmation">Confirm password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="fadeIn third" id="passwordConfirmation" name="passwordConfirmation" required>
                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary fadeIn fourth button"
                            id="submitRegistration">Register</button>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

or u can make Json Object using javascript and send that data with AJAX.

Comment: I did it the ModelAttribute annotation way but the request was: "RegistrationRequest(username=null, email=null, password=null, passwordConfirmation=null)"

Comment: ModelAttribute annotation mapping values via Setter method. how about attach @Setter annotation on RegistrationRequest  class?

Comment: Added the @Setter annotation and removed the final key words. I also removed the ajax call and now it works. Thanks. <3

Comment: glad to hear that!